# How to add url in onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code

```
new_element.innerHTML ="<a href='#'><img src='"+imagePath+"' alt='' title='' width='466' onclick='addWidget('"+url+"');' height='165'></a>";
```

which will call the function addWidget:

```
function addWidget(url) {
  alert(url);
  var main= document.getElementById('mainwidget'); 
  main.innerHTML = "<iframe src='"+url+"' align='left' height='1060px' width='576px' scrolling='no'  frameborder='0' id='lodex'></iframe>";
}
```

but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should troubleshoot this more first. How doesn't it work? Are there any errors in the error log? What does the DOM for new_element look like when viewed in a DOM inspector?

Answer (score 0):

Since the iframe with it's src url is being dynamically set in client script, there is no GET being done against the dynamically generated url for the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

First I agree with psd commend, **you need to see whats the error messages on the console.**

**How ever I can not regist to say that you have warp the image with the link** **a** handler, probably because you won to see the mouse icon to change over the image.

So its better to place the event on the link and not on the image:

```
   new_element.innerHTML =
  '<a href="#" onclick="return addWidget("' + url + '");"><img src="' + imagePath + '" ></a>';
```

Also note that I swap the **"** with **'**, and **need the addWidget return false**.

Answer (score 0):

new_element.innerHTML ="";

Answer (score 0):

```
new_element.innerHTML ="<a href='#'><img src='"+imagePath+"' alt='' title='' width='466' onclick='addWidget("+url+");' height='165'></a>";
```